# Visual Studio OpenGL library linking - Error cannot open library file

Tags: c, visual-studio, opengl

I am attempting to run some legacy OpenGL code using Microsoft Visual Studio. I have linked the libraries via project -> properties -> linker -> input

The files I have added here are all 64 bit: `GlU64.lib, glut64.lib`. The additional library directory is the folder containing only these 64 bit library files.

`glut64.dll` is also in my system `PATH`.

However, when I attempt to run, I get the error: `LNK110: cannot open file 'glut32.lib'`.

I am not sure why this error is occurring, as I am running Local Windows Debugger as x64, and I made sure that my linker input was only 64 bit .lib files. Why is Visual Studio still trying to read a 32 bit library?

Project file contents -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="src\curve.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="src\dot.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="src\ogl.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="src\ogl_model.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="src\ogl_model_ply.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="src\tcl_if.c" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="src\def.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="src\main.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <VCProjectVersion>15.0</VCProjectVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{603EEE3D-C785-48DC-8046-46E63FCCC629}</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>tkogl2</RootNamespace>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="Shared">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <OutDir>..\GUImorph\inst\libs\i386\</OutDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <OutDir>..\GUImorph\inst\libs\x64\</OutDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <OutDir>..\rtkogl\inst\libs\i386\</OutDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>C:\Users\amlut\Documents\RESEARCH\GUIMORPH\guimorph_austin1\tkogl2\include\tcl_include;C:\Users\amlut\Documents\RESEARCH\GUIMORPH\guimorph_austin1\tkogl2\include\tk_include;C:\Users\amlut\Documents\RESEARCH\GUIMORPH\guimorph_austin1\tkogl2\include\tk_include\ttk;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>USE_TCL_STUBS;_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS;_USING_V110_SDK71_;_MBCS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDebug</RuntimeLibrary>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>C:\Users\amlut\Documents\RESEARCH\GUIMORPH\guimorph_austin1\tkogl2\lib</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>GlU64.lib;glut64.lib;tclstub86_64.lib;tkstub86.lib</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>C:\Users\amlut\Documents\RESEARCH\GUIMORPH\guimorph_austin1\tkogl2\include\tcl_include;C:\Users\amlut\Documents\RESEARCH\GUIMORPH\guimorph_austin1\tkogl2\include\tk_include;C:\Users\amlut\Documents\RESEARCH\GUIMORPH\guimorph_austin1\tkogl2\include\tk_include\ttk;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>USE_TCL_STUBS;_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS;_USING_V110_SDK71_;_MBCS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDebug</RuntimeLibrary>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>C:\Users\amlut\Documents\RESEARCH\GUIMORPH\guimorph_austin1\tkogl2\lib</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>GlU64.lib;glut64.lib;tclstub86_64.lib;tkstub86.lib</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>USE_TCL_STUBS;_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS;_USING_V110_SDK71_;_MBCS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>C:\Users\amlut\Documents\RESEARCH\GUIMORPH\guimorph_austin1\tkogl2\include\tcl_include;C:\Users\amlut\Documents\RESEARCH\GUIMORPH\guimorph_austin1\tkogl2\include\tk_include;C:\Users\amlut\Documents\RESEARCH\GUIMORPH\guimorph_austin1\tkogl2\include\tk_include\ttk;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>C:\Users\amlut\Documents\RESEARCH\GUIMORPH\guimorph_austin1\tkogl2\lib</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>GlU64.lib;glut64.lib;tclstub86_64.lib;tkstub86.lib</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>C:\Users\amlut\Documents\RESEARCH\GUIMORPH\guimorph_austin1\tkogl2\include\tcl_include;C:\Users\amlut\Documents\RESEARCH\GUIMORPH\guimorph_austin1\tkogl2\include\tk_include;C:\Users\amlut\Documents\RESEARCH\GUIMORPH\guimorph_austin1\tkogl2\include\tk_include\ttk;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>C:\Users\amlut\Documents\RESEARCH\GUIMORPH\guimorph_austin1\tkogl2\lib</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>GlU64.lib;glut64.lib;tclstub86_64.lib;tkstub86.lib</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: That's an error when linking, not when starting your project. Can you provide the contents of your project file?

Comment: Would that be `"projectname".vcxproj`?

Comment: It is. --------

Comment: Added ---------

Comment: I suspect that the dependency is coming from a [`#pragma comment(lib, "glut32.lib")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/comment-c-cpp?view=vs-2019) directive somewhere in either your source code or one of the libraries you are explicitly linking. Are you sure that `tkstub86.lib`, for one, is 64-bit?

Comment: Good question. I will see if I can find that out as I am not sure.

Comment: It appears tkstub86.lib is in fact not 64 bit. So that is probably causing the issue.

Comment: Review your configs, I see `glu64.lib` in a 32 target. And don't forget to add `opengl32.lib` in all targets despite they are 32 or 64. I'm not sure, but I think this same 32/64 versions apply also to `glu`, it must always be `glu32.lib`